# Dynamically generated javascript img tag firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm having trouble with a screen containing dynamically generated images, when viewed in Chrome it functions as expected, images get generated no problem. However in Firefox none of the images end up being generated and the user is shown a set of image not loaded boxes.

```
function popupPermanentOverlay_Walking(locationName) {
var title = "Walking to "+locationName;
var content = "Content_Text<div class='walkimg-container'><img class='walkimg' src='images/anim/walkimg.gif'/>";
for(var i = 0; i<50; i++)
{
    var filename = "";
    var type=random(0,5);
    if (type==0)
        filename = "tree";
    else if (type==1)
        filename = "tree";
    else if (type==2)
        filename = "shrub";
    else if (type==3)
        filename = "shrub";
    else if (type==4)
        filename = "shrub";
    else if (type==5)
        filename = "baretree";

    if (filename == "tree")
        filename+=random(1,6);
    else if (filename == "shrub")
        filename+=random(1,3);
    else if (filename == "baretree")
        filename+=random(1,7);

    var y = random(-60, 60);
    content+="<img class='walking-prop' src='images/anim/props/"+filename+".gif' style='bottom:"+(y-7)+"px; left:"+random(-50,720)+"px;z-index:"+(15000-y)+";' />";
}

for(var i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    var filename = "grass";

    if (random(1,2)==1)
        filename+=random(1,6);
    else
        filename+=random(3,6);


    var y = random(-100, 100);
    content+="<img class='walking-prop' src='images/anim/props/"+filename+".gif' style='bottom:"+(y)+"px; left:"+random(-180,720)+"px;z-index:"+(10000-y)+";' />";
}
content+="</div>";
popupPermanentOverlay(title, content, "walking-popup");
$(".walkimg").animate({left: "+=600px"}, 20000, "linear");
```

}

I know Firefox sometimes has an issue of loading the page before images are ready, but I have tried adding a check to ensure it has loaded to no effect.

Ideally I would like to avoid preloading the images which I know is a potential fix for this.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle demonstrating the error

Comment: Can you check your developerTools -> network panel to see what's going on?

Comment: Ok so in the Network panel its showing each image in order. Method: GET FILE:image_name.gif DOMAIN: my.domain TYPE: Plain TRANSFERRED: - SIZE: 0KB. For the timings I get approx 50ms each for connecting, then nothing for sending waiting or recieving

Comment: And I guess the status is `204` which means `no-content`. So it seems those files are empty. I don't know how to help you without your files, server settings etc. Sorry.

Comment: Actually the status code is `304` `Not Modified` for the image that is not loaded dynamically and then no status code for any of the others...

Comment: 304 is because it's now in cache. What do you have if you deliberately provide a wrong url?